# Micronaut cannot convert CompletableFuture<Set<Pojo>>?

Tags: json, jackson, completable-future, micronaut

I've created an enpoint with the following signature:

```
@Status(HttpStatus.ACCEPTED)
public CompletableFuture<String> processTagsInBatch(@Body CompletableFuture<Set<TagBatchRequest>> tagsRequests) {
return tagsRequests.thenApply(t -> doSomething(t));
```

But i get the following error: 
`class java.util.LinkedHashMap cannot be cast to class com.xyz.TagBatchRequest (java.util.LinkedHashMap is in module java.base of loader 'bootstrap';`

Comment: Could you show your `JSON` payload?

Comment: You'd have to post an example app. I can't reproduce the error